# Closed-form solution of extrinsic in 2D to 3D projection problem

Tags: calibration

The title is pretty much it.

Anyone have seen a closed-form solution of extrinsic on 2D to 3D projection problem?

Seems like this should exist in old camera calibration literature but I can't really find it.

Comment: You essentially mean how to obtain a depth map from a 2D image?

Comment: Hey, it is not related to depth map generation. I know 3D points and their projected location on the 2D image. I would like to find the extrinsic that exactly projecting the 3D points on the 2D locations. The numerical solution works given a fair initial guess but I was wondering if there is a closed form solution.